# PHP Array always has parent 0 Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I Have an array in PHP. For some reason that I can't figure out It always has a parent array of the key [0]. I'm not sure why This is happening. I have the array as a foreach statement. The Data that displays is correct in the arrays. How can I get this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [DB_ID] => 8umad0aqpt7re9
                    [Name] => Customers
                    [Record_Name] => Customer
                    [Description] => Customers Database
                    [Count] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [DB_ID] => 37vcv0ab8hwtx9
                    [Name] => Estimates
                    [Record_Name] => Bid
                    [Description] => Estimates Database
                    [Count] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [DB_ID] => 8nhenyhnh5tal9
                    [Name] => Customers
                    [Record_Name] => Customer
                    [Description] => Customers Database
                    [Count] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

TO This Array:

```
Array
(
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [DB_ID] => 8umad0aqpt7re9
                    [Name] => Customers
                    [Record_Name] => Customer
                    [Description] => Customers Database
                    [Count] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [DB_ID] => 37vcv0ab8hwtx9
                    [Name] => Estimates
                    [Record_Name] => Bid
                    [Description] => Estimates Database
                    [Count] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [DB_ID] => 8nhenyhnh5tal9
                    [Name] => Customers
                    [Record_Name] => Customer
                    [Description] => Customers Database
                    [Count] => 0
                )

)
```

My PHP:

```
$user_id = DBMGR::Auth();

SQL::Query("SELECT * FROM `".USER_ROLES_TBL."` WHERE `".USER_ROLES_ID."` = :user_id;");
SQL::Bind(":user_id", $user_id);
$Allowed_Databases = SQL::Results();
$Allowed_Databases = Encryption::DecryptArray($Allowed_Databases);

$List_Databases = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($Allowed_Databases as $key => $db){
    SQL::Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `" . $db[USER_ROLES_DB_ID] . "`.`".MAIN_TBL."`;");
    $count = SQL::Single();
    $count = $count['COUNT(*)'];

    SQL::Query("SELECT * FROM `main`.`".DATABASE_TBL."` WHERE `".DATABASE_ID."` = :db_id;");
    SQL::Bind(":db_id", $db[USER_ROLES_DB_ID]);
    $DB_Info = SQL::Single();
    $DB_Info = Encryption::DecryptSingleArray($DB_Info);

    $List_Databases[$i]['DB_ID'] = $DB_Info[DATABASE_ID];
    $List_Databases[$i]['Name'] = $DB_Info[DATABASE_NAME];
    $List_Databases[$i]['Record_Name'] = $DB_Info[DATABASE_RECORD_NAME];
    $List_Databases[$i]['Description'] = $DB_Info[DATABASE_DESCRIPION];
    $List_Databases[$i]['Count'] = $count;
    $i++;

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($List_Databases);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Are you sure you are printing out the same array here and on your machine? The syntax/idea seems to be right so far. Also, have you tried to go step-by-step, e.g. printing out on the first iteration and then breaking the cycle or breakpointing the code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your query code a bit like below:-

```
 SQL::Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `" . $db[USER_ROLES_DB_ID] . "`.`".MAIN_TBL."`;");
```

Full code:-

```
$user_id = DBMGR::Auth();

SQL::Query("SELECT * FROM `".USER_ROLES_TBL."` WHERE `".USER_ROLES_ID."` = :user_id;");
SQL::Bind(":user_id", $user_id);
$Allowed_Databases = SQL::Results();
$Allowed_Databases = Encryption::DecryptArray($Allowed_Databases);

$List_Databases = array();

foreach($Allowed_Databases as $key => $db){
    SQL::Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `" . $db[USER_ROLES_DB_ID] . "`.`".MAIN_TBL."`;");
    $count = SQL::Single();
    $count = $count['COUNT(*)'];

    SQL::Query("SELECT * FROM `main`.`".DATABASE_TBL."` WHERE `".DATABASE_ID."` = :db_id;");
    SQL::Bind(":db_id", $db[USER_ROLES_DB_ID]);
    $DB_Info = SQL::Single();
    $DB_Info = Encryption::DecryptSingleArray($DB_Info);
$new_array = array();//created new array inside foreach
    //assigning values to this array

    $new_array['DB_ID'] = $DB_Info[DATABASE_ID]; // REMOVE $i so that extra indexes will not made
    $new_array['Name'] = $DB_Info[DATABASE_NAME];
    $new_array['Record_Name'] = $DB_Info[DATABASE_RECORD_NAME];
    $new_array['Description'] = $DB_Info[DATABASE_DESCRIPION];
    $new_array['Count'] = $count;
    $List_Databases = array_push($List_Databases,$new_array[0]);// push it into resultant array
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($List_Databases);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Note:- remove `$i=0` and `$i++;` in foreach loop.**